# How to implement Circular Broadcast in android

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-sharing

I have two applications let us say **App1** and **App2**. Now App1 is already working which has multiple responsibilities. Now i have developed App2 which is actually a background helper app to divide the responsibilities of App1. Now because App1 is already live and i want smooth and un-interrupted process so when App2 launches it should ask App1 to shutdown its services(responsibilities) and give necessary parameters to App2 so that it can Start(up) its services.
Now since i have heard that **circular broadcast** will do the work but i couldn't find any documentation or exact functionality which is doing this.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Circular Broadcast is not a theoretical term and it is just being used in market. So, in simple words communication between **App A** and **App B** through `Broadcast` where App B must have to respond against action of App A is Circular broadcast. Here is solution.
App A Manifest:

```
<receiver  
        android:name=".AppAReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="APP_A_RECEIVER_FILTER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

App A Receiver:

```
class AppAReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val data = intent?.getStringExtra("data")
        // Here you can do your work and on response given by app B

    }
}
```

App B Manifest

```
<receiver  
        android:name=".AppBReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="APP_B_RECEIVER_FILTER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

App B Broadcast receiver:

```
class AppBReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            val data = intent?.getStringExtra("data")
            // Here you can do your work and on response given by app A
    
        }
    }
```

Finally how to send Broadcast from each app so here is the method:

```
fun sendBroadcast(context: Context, data: String? = null) {
        val serviceIntent = Intent("APP_B_RECEIVER_FILTER").apply {
            this.putExtra("data", data)
            this.setPackage("<App B Package Name>")
        }

        context.sendBroadcast(serviceIntent)
    }
```

**Note 1:** The `sendBroadcast` method is showing how you can send broadcast from A to app B, you need to copy same method and update Intent String and packageName to make it work.

**Note 2:** These are app level broadcast and doesn't need to be registered with Activities, therefore to make it work, Apps only need to run at least once so that app process can register Broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of circular broadcast either, but you can communicate with others apps (including yours) on Android device over broadcast messages.

In your **App1** you need to define [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver). `BroadcastReceiver` defines a filter which will be used by `Intent`. This filter allows you to to tell your **App1** which `Intent` it could accept including ones that could be send only by yours application. Take a look on [custom permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/defining) and [custom intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/custom-intents)

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085502/custom-permission-with-implicit-intent) just a sample of `BroadcastReceiver` usage.

Please also note there is such thing like [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element) which is designed to share app's database with others android apps. It also has an option of granular access.